# Why is ListChangeBuilder throwing a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.findSubChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:68)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.insertAdd(ListChangeBuilder.java:127)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.nextAdd(ListChangeBuilder.java:254)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.nextAdd(ObservableListBase.java:179)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.add(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:153)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at tech.dashman.dashman.RendererApp$1.handle(RendererApp.java:72)
    at tech.dashman.common.pubnub.NewScreenshotsToRender.handle(NewScreenshotsToRender.java:17)
    at tech.dashman.dashman.PubNubMessageHandler.lambda$message$0(PubNubMessageHandler.java:79)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It happened twice on my application but I don't know how to reproduce it. The line in my code that triggers the error is this:

```
getActivity().add(new ActivityEntry("..."));
```

`ActivityEntry` is a simple class with two fields. I can post the code if necessary but I think it's irrelevant. `activity`, what `getActivity()` returns, is a field defined like this:

```
private ObservableList<ActivityEntry> activity = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

The method in which the actual exception is happening looks like this:

```
private int findSubChange(int idx, final List<ListChangeBuilder.SubChange<E>> list) {
    int from = 0;
    int to = list.size() - 1;

    while (from <= to) {
        int changeIdx  = (from + to) / 2;
        ListChangeBuilder.SubChange<E> change = list.get(changeIdx);

        if (idx >= change.to) {
            from = changeIdx + 1;
        } else if (idx < change.from) {
            to = changeIdx - 1;
        } else {
            return changeIdx;
        }
    }
    return ~from;
}
```

Line 68, the one raising the exception is:

```
if (idx >= change.to) {
```

The only thing I can think of, other than a bug in `ListChangeBuilder`, is that it was a race condition and two threads modified the `ObservableList` at the same time. Does this look like that? Is `ObservableList` not thread safe?

Comment: I think this can happen when a change is made to the list while another change listener is firing. I've seen this happen before, but I'm not sure if it's a bug in JavaFX or simply a (not well documented) design limitation.

Comment: `ObservableList` is not thread safe. Are you modifying it from a background thread somewhere - that's not apparent from your code? It is also true that it's a design limitation that a list cannot be modified while a change is being processed.

Comment: For the latter point, see the warnings in the [`Change` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a multi-threading issue, so, for now, my solution is to define the list this way:

```
private ObservableList<ActivityEntry> activity = FXCollections.synchronizedObservableList(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
```

Since multi-threading issues are so hard to reproduce and debug, I don't know whether this really solves the problem. I'm guessing if it doesn't I'll notice it again in production.